# How to declare a ruby constant (RMagick) in a YAML file

Tags: ruby, constants, configuration-files, rmagick

I am looking for a possibility to declare a Magick::StyleType constant in a .yml file and then to load this constant into a ruby file.
Or if that's not possible then I need to know how to convert a String into a Magick::StyleType constant in ruby.

Here are the details:

I am trying to write a ruby program, which places some text on a picture and I use the RMagick interface for it. 
In my ruby program I have a method which specifies different properties of the text like font-family or font-style. This method includes the line:

```
self.font_style = ItalicStyle
```

Now I want to store all changeable parameters in a YAML-config file (config.yml), so this config.yml includes these lines:

```
#font style (like bold, italic and so on)
:font_style: ItalicStyle
```

Now I load the config.yml in my ruby file and the above mentioned line in my method reads now

```
self.font_style = config_file[:font_style]
```

When I run my ruby file now I get the error message:

```
`font_style=': wrong enumeration type - expected Magick::StyleType, got String (TypeError)
```

So after having searched a little about the topic I changed my config.yml first to

```
:font_style: !/ruby/constant ItalicStyle
```

which got me the same error message as above and then I tried this:

```
:font_style: !/ruby/symbol :ItalicStyle
```

and got this error message:

```
`font_style=': wrong enumeration type - expected Magick::StyleType, got Symbol (TypeError)
```

Then I checked in irb:

```
require 'rmagick' => true

Magick.const_get(ItalicStyle) => ItalicStyle=2
Magick.const_get(ItalicStyle).class => Magick::StyleType
```

So, finally I get to my question: How do I need to change the line

```
:font_style: !/ruby/symbol :ItalicStyle
```

in my config.yml file so that when loaded into my ruby file ItalicStyle will be recognized as a Magick::StyleType constant?

Or when I leave

```
:font_style: ItalicStyle
```

in the config.yml and load the ItalicStyle as a String into my ruby file: is there a possibility, to convert ItalicStyle from a String to the Magick:StyleType constant in the ruby file directly?

I would be really happy if someone could help. I have tried for days to find a solution and I really need it for my project.

Comment: What’s wrong with **dumping** the defaults into yaml to examine what they should look like? For the proper solution see the answer by @spickermann below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just store a `String` in the `YAML` file, because that is easier to write and to read:

```
:font_style: ItalicStyle
```

Than I would get the constant by its name to configure `Magick`:

```
self.font_style = Object.const_get(config_file[:font_style])
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I have one more question: I tried the const_get method in irb already previous to posting the question. But here's what I don't understand:

Comment: In my ruby-program the line "self.font_style = Object.const_get(config_file[:font_style])" does work. But when I start irb and type there "require 'rmagick'" and then "Object.const_get("ItalicStyle")" then I receive an error "NameError: uninitialized constant ItalicStyle". Why is that?

Comment: You will have to require rmagick first. You probably do that in your app, but didn't do that in the irb console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, in irb first I type "require 'rmagick'" => true. Then I type "Object.const_get("ItalicStyle")" and then I get the NameError I mentioned before. But "Magick.const_get("ItalicStyle")" returns "ItalicStyle=2". In the ruby program both versions work. Puzzling...